# Calling a function that return a table with dates

Tags: sql, oracle, function, date

I have a problem with a function.
I need to get a table with dates of a month, name of the day and the amound of weekdays in that month. 
I already found some help here and adapted it to my need, but I can't get the function running/compiled
Here is what I have so far:

```
create or replace TYPE DATE_ROW AS OBJECT
(
  MyDate DATE,
  Dayname VARCHAR2(12),
  Amount Integer
 )

create or replace TYPE DATE_TABLE as table of DATE_ROW

create or replace FUNCTION myfinaldays (mydate date)
       RETURN DATE_TABLE
       PIPELINED
    IS
       V_MYDATE          DATE;
       V_DAYNAME   VARCHAR2(12);
       V_AMOUNT           NUMBER;
BEGIN
    with this_month as (
        select trunc(to_date('mydate'), 'mm')+level-1 dy
          from dual 
       connect by level < (trunc(add_months(to_date('mydate'),1), 'mm')- trunc(to_date('mydate'), 'mm'))+1
    )
    FOR i IN 0 .. (select count(*) from this_month) LOOP
        select (dy) Daydate,
               to_char(dy, 'day'), Dayname,
              ( select count(*)
                  from this_month 
                 where  to_char(dy, 'dy') not in ('sat', 'sun')
               ) Amount
          from this_month
         where to_char(dy, 'dy') not in ('sat', 'sun')
           and EXTRACT(day from to_date(dy)) = i;

       pipe row (date_row(v_mydate,v_dayname, v_amount));
   END LOOP;
   RETURN;
   END;
```

The function call would then be something like:

```
select * from date_table(cast(myfinaldays('01.02.12')));
```

I can only give one date as a parameter.

I hope someone can help me out here since this is slowly driving me mad.
Any ideas, examples, or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Ok here is an update with mybe some more helpfull infos to my problem:

This is working and my aim is to put this in a function so I can call it with 1 parameter:

```
    with this_month as (  
    select trunc(to_date('01.02.12'), 'mm')+level-1 dy
    from   dual 
    connect by level < (trunc(add_months(to_date('01.02.12'),1), 'mm')- trunc(to_date('01.02.12'), 'mm'))+1
    )
    select (dy) mydate, (select count(*) from this_month) Days_in_month
    ,      to_char(dy, 'day') Dayname
    ,     ( select count(*) from this_month where  to_char(dy, 'dy') not in ('sat', 'sun') ) Amount
    from   this_month
    where  to_char(dy, 'dy') not in ('sat', 'sun') ;
```

for the loop I added: 'and  EXTRACT(day from to_date(dy))=i' at the end.

I added a date so you can see what I need in the end. If I write mydate instead and enter 01.02.12 as parameter after running it in the developer it still works.

Errors I get compiling:
    - Error(10,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

```
- Error(15,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00928: Keyword SELECT missing

- Error(22,8): PLS-00113: END-Definer 'LOOP' must complete 'myfinaldays' in row 1, comlumn 10 

- Error(23,4): PLS-00103: Found the symbol "RETURN"
```

The errors are translated since my Oracle does not run english so I hope to have guessed it correctly.

Comment: Are you getting an error compiling the function, or calling it; and either way what error do you get? I don't think you can use a `with` clause as 'input' to a `for` loop like that, you're mixing SQL and PL/SQL. You may need to build a PL/SQL table to hold the generated dates. But for starters, `to_date('mydate')`; `mydate` is already a date, and `'mydate'` is a string that has no relation to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of problems here.

- You can't use a `select` directly in `for i in 1..x` (and it should be 1, not 0), you'd have to select into a local variable and use that as the end value.
- You can't use `with` as an input to a `for` loop; but you can use a cursor there, as I have below.
- The select inside the loop with get no-data-found when `i` represents a Saturday or Sunday (the 4th in this case, assuming you're running it for February).
- Getting the count of all non-weekend rows for every row is inefficient, though it doesn't really matter for such a small amount of data.
- You are referring to `to_date('mydate')`; mydate is already a date, and 'mydate' is a string that has no relation to it.

And maybe some other things too, like assuming the date format and locale, since `to_char(x, 'dy')` will not return `sat` or `sun` everywhere, but I'll assume this is going to be used in a restricted way so you don't care about that too much.

From trying to figure out what output you're expecting, I think this will work (with modified types to get the `days_in_month` you added to the original question):

```
create or replace type date_row as object
(
    mydate DATE,
    dayname VARCHAR2(12),
    days_in_month NUMBER,
    amount NUMBER
)
/

create or replace type date_table as table of date_row
/

create or replace function myfinaldays (mydate date)
return date_table pipelined deterministic is
begin
    for r in (
        select *
        from (
            select dy as daydate,
                to_char(dy, 'day') as dayname,
                count(*) over () as days_in_month,
                sum(case when to_char(dy, 'dy') in ('sat', 'sun')
                    then 0 else 1 end) over () as amount
            from (
                select trunc(mydate, 'mm')+level-1 dy
                from dual 
                connect by level < (trunc(add_months(mydate, 1), 'mm')
                    - trunc(mydate, 'mm')) + 1
            )
        )
        where to_char(daydate, 'dy') not in ('sat', 'sun')
    ) loop
       pipe row (date_row(r.daydate, r.dayname, r.days_in_month, r.amount));
    end loop;
end myfinaldays;
/
```

(If you don't want `days_in_month` then you can move the `sat`/`sun` check up and use the `count` for `amount` instead of the `sum(case)`. The outer `select` is currently filtering on the day of the week so you can count all days, but that's not an issue if you don't want that value).

Then call as:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD.MM.RR';
select * from table(myfinaldays(to_date('01.02.12', 'DD.MM.RR')));

MYDATE   DAYNAME      DAYS_IN_MONTH     AMOUNT
-------- ------------ ------------- ----------
01.02.12 wednesday               29         21
02.02.12 thursday                29         21
03.02.12 friday                  29         21
06.02.12 monday                  29         21
...
29.02.12 wednesday               29         21

21 rows selected.
```

Comment: WOW thanks sooo much. Yes that did it. I guess I'm going to have a special look at that code so I understand what it is doing at each step. 1 more thing though: Now it should be possible that I work with this table like with any other right? like 'Select mydate from table(myfinaldays(to_date('01.02.12', 'DD.MM.RR'))) where mydate not in (select date from holidaycalendar)'or with left join, union or so.... I have to test what works best. Just guessing the syntax on that step but I am sure you understand what I mean.

Comment: OK got it to work with everything I need... thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Thevagabond - no problem. You can treat it as a table, but I'd be a bit wary of passing a field from another table in as the `mydate` parameter. For excluding holiday dates, you *might* want to do that inside the function so you don't have to repeat that elsewhere. If you haven't already, please see [the FAQ] for how to acknowledge helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function is a table valued function (returns a table), you cannot call it as regular function.
 you have join with it:

something like this in Oracle:

```
select * from date_table t
cross join table( myfinaldays(<t.date colum>))
```

Comment: `date_table` is a type; shouldn't this just be `select * from table(myfinaldays(to_date('01.02.12','DD.MM.RR'))`? (Guessing the date format of course, but prefer to see an explicit conversion).

Comment: @Alex Poole
The first problem ist that the function itself won't compile.. and I can't it fixed. But thanks for your advice I guess that would have been the next problem I ran into.